# bot.wait_for("select_option") ничего не возвращает

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

```py
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    b = Select(placeholder = "Выберите раздел",
                options = [
                    SelectOption(label = "Настройка бота", value = "Настройка бота"),
                    SelectOption(label = "Команды", value = "Команды"),
                    SelectOption(label = "Форматирование текста", value = "Форматирование текста")
                ]
            )
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Выберите раздел:", color=int(hex(int("9de300", 16)), 0))
    embed1 = discord.Embed(title="Настройка бота:", color=int(hex(int("9de300", 16)), 0))
    embed2 = discord.Embed(title="Команды:", color=int(hex(int("9de300", 16)), 0))
    embed3 = discord.Embed(title="Форматирование текста:", color=int(hex(int("9de300", 16)), 0))
    choose = {"Настройка бота": embed1, "Команды": embed2, "Форматирование текста": embed3}
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed, components=[b])
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("select_option")
    await message.edit(embed=choose[interaction])
```

Никаких ошибок я не получаю, выбор просто игнорируется[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Answer (score 0, accepted):

```
@bot.command()
async def help(ctx):
    b = Select(placeholder = "Выберите раздел",
                options = [
                    SelectOption(label = "Настройка бота", value = "Настройка бота"),
                    SelectOption(label = "Команды", value = "Команды"),
                    SelectOption(label = "Форматирование текста", value = "Форматирование текста")
                ]
            )
    embed = discord.Embed(title="Выберите раздел:", color=int(hex(int("9de300", 16)), 0))
    embed1 = discord.Embed(title="Настройка бота:", color=int(hex(int("9de300", 16)), 0))
    embed2 = discord.Embed(title="Команды:", color=int(hex(int("9de300", 16)), 0))
    embed3 = discord.Embed(title="Форматирование текста:", color=int(hex(int("9de300", 16)), 0))
    choose = {"Настройка бота": embed1, "Команды": embed2, "Форматирование текста": embed3}
    message = await ctx.send(embed=embed, components=[b])
    interaction = await bot.wait_for("select_option")
    await message.edit(embed=choose[interaction.label])
```

Comment: Возможно это могло быть еще одной ошибкой, но дело в том, что строчки кода после `interaction = await bot.wait_for("select_option")` по какой-то причине никогда не выполняются, даже если например туда написать `print("Hello World!")`.

Comment: ну дк правильно, идёт ожидание нажатия

Comment: я нажимаю, после получаю ошибку взаимодействия